# how do I delete a project release node

Tags: 7

I accidentally created a stable release for a module instead of dev. So now how do I delete the stable release node on drupal.org

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can file an issue for webmaster to delete the nodes. But in this case they usually don't delete release node and only option is to create new release.

check: https://www.drupal.org/node/128614